# React/Babel proposal class properties

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I have a simple project in `React`, that I'm using `react-swipeable-views`.
My `package.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.14.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-favicon": "^2.0.1",
    "gsap": "^3.5.0",
    "leaflet": "^1.6.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-leaflet": "^2.7.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.3",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.1",
    "react-swipeable-views": "^0.13.9",
    "react-swipeable-views-utils": "^0.13.9",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "start_react": "react-scripts start",
    "build_react": "react-scripts build",
    "heroku_local": "heroku local",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.+(js|jsx|json|css|md)\"",
    "push": "git push heroku master"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-property-arrow-functions": "^1.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^3.6.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.6",
    "file-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
    ]
  }
}
```

I installed `@babel / plugin-proposal-class-properties` and tried many options: `.babelrc` / `babel.config.js`, nothing helps. I still get the error:

```
  197 | 
  198 | class SwipeableViews extends React.Component {
> 199 |   rootNode = null;
      |            ^
  200 | 
  201 |   containerNode = null;
  202 | 

Add @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties (https://git.io/vb4SL) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
```

Comment: Can you post your .babelrc?

Comment: It is practically the same as in  ```package.json```
```{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
}```

Comment: Perhaps this [issue](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8577) can help you